# Why does original list get overridden when I modify .copy()?

Tags: python, list, copy

I have this piece of code that accomplishes a text sequence processing task. It generally does what I want, but when I make a copy of one of my lists, the original gets modified. See below:

```html
list_1 = [
      {'word': 'hey hows it going?', 's1': 1.2, 's2': 3.6},
      {'word': 'um', 's1': 3.7, 's2': 4.2},
      {'word': 'its raining outside today', 's1': 4.3, 's2': 5.0},
      {'word': 'and its really cold', 's1': 5.1, 's2': 6.6},
      {'word': 'dont you think?', 's1': 6.7, 's2': 7.6},
      {'word': 'its awful', 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0}
]
list_2 = [
  {'category': 0, 's1': 0.0, 's2': 3.8},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 3.9, 's2': 4.9},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 5.0, 's2': 7.2},
  {'category': 0, 's1': 7.3, 's2': 7.6},
  {'category': 1, 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0}
]


def combine_dicts(list_1, list_2):
    
    outputs = []

    for cat in list_2:
        start = cat['s1']
        end = cat['s2']
        out = copy(cat)
        out['words'] = ''
        outputs.append(out)
        list_1_copy = list_1.copy()

        for interval in list_1_copy:
            if interval['s1'] >= start and interval['s2'] <= end:
                out['words'] += interval['word'] + ' '
                interval['word'] = ''
            elif interval['s1'] <= start and interval['s2'] <= end:
                out['words'] += interval['word'] + ' '
                interval['word'] = ''
        out['words'] = out['words'].strip()
    pprint.pprint(outputs)
    
combine_dicts(list_1, list_2)
```

In the first for loop, I make a copy of list_1, which is list_1_copy, so that I can remove items from it as I iterate through it, without effecting the original, list_1. However, running the code always removes items from list_1 and list_1_copy.

I thought I had an understanding of the copy() function, for example, I want the result to be like this:

```html
list_to_not_change = [1,2,3]
list_to_change = list_to_not_change.copy()

while list_to_change:
    list_to_change.pop(0)
    
print(list_to_not_change)
print(list_to_change)

Output:
[1, 2, 3]
[]
```

Where is my code/understanding wrong and why does the original list_1 become modified in my code? Thank you for any advice.

If useful, the output of my algorithm is:

```html
[{'category': 0, 's1': 0.0, 's2': 3.8, 'words': 'hey hows it going?'},
 {'category': 1, 's1': 3.9, 's2': 4.9, 'words': 'um'},
 {'category': 1,
  's1': 5.0,
  's2': 7.2,
  'words': 'its raining outside today and its really cold'},
 {'category': 0, 's1': 7.3, 's2': 7.6, 'words': 'dont you think?'},
 {'category': 1, 's1': 7.7, 's2': 9.0, 'words': 'its awful'}]
```

Comment: Because `.copy()` is only *shallow*, and your list contains mutable dictionaries.

Comment: `copy()` makes a separate copy of _the list itself_, but not _the objects in the list_.  For that, you need `deepcopy()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `deepcopy`:

Deep copy is a process in which the copying process occurs recursively. It means first constructing a new collection object and then recursively populating it with copies of the child objects found in the original. In case of deep copy, a copy of object is copied in other object. It means that any changes made to a copy of object do not reflect in the original object. In python, this is implemented using `deepcopy()` function.

```
copy.deepcopy()
```

ex:

```
import copy 

# initializing list 1 
li1 = [1, 2, [3,5], 4] 

# using deepcopy to deep copy  
li2 = copy.deepcopy(li1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a shallow copy.  `list_1_copy` has its own list -- but the list *elements* were not similarly copied, so the two lists share the same `dict` elements.  When you change any `dict` value, that change is reflected in both lists.

You need to use `deepcopy` to separate them entirely.